# How to access local variables from multilevel nested function in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code

```
x=55
def show():
    x=10
    def show1():
        x=20
        def show2():
            x=30
            # how we can print x of show here
            print(x)
```

how can we access x of show from show2. pl update

Comment: How do you call your function? Have tried with the `global` keyword? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: which function. global can call x which is 55 here.

Comment: You've just added it. Why give all these variables the same name? I was asking how you call `show2`. Please add code that others can run.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of a variable is defined until you are in that function. To simplify your analogy:

```
x = 10 # ref as p
def show():
    x = 20 # ref as q
    def show1():
        x = 30 # ref as r
        print(x)
    print(x)

show()
```

1. Before calling the show(), 'p' acts as a global variable.
2. Calling show() -> you are overriding 'p' with 'q'. In better terms, 'q' is the local variable and gets preference over 'p'.
3. Calling show1() from inside show(), 'r' overrides 'q' as the local variable.

Comment: the question is not this. it is how to call x of show from within show2 which is nested one level below show

Comment: You can't, that's what I explained with an example. Try different variable names.